# Vehicle specification information by VIN lookup

Tags: vehicle-identification, vin

I was curious if there was a site to look up vehicle manufacturer specification on a vehicle by its VIN?

For example, I'm interested in buy some new rotors and calipers but I want to find the exact measurements before doing so (i.e. - what are the sizes of bolts in the front rotors, rear, etc.). And not that I don't trust information from third party websites to have this information but I want to make sure everything fits when I take everything out.

For my specific case, I have my 2007 Subaru Impreza 2.5i but I can't find any information on the braking system in the owner's manual.

Also, I tried searching on sites like the ones below but they don't contain the specific information that I want.

https://www.searchquarry.com/vin-decoder/ 
DMV VIn lookup

Let me know, thanks.

Comment: The vin detail most probably will not give detail of bolts and sizes but normally does specify equipment fitted : radio type, tyres, trim level etc

Comment: You need the service manual, not the owner's manual. Or, easier: call the dealer and ask them. They probably won't have bolt sizes, etc., but they'll have part numbers. If you're just doing brakes, you shouldn't really need any new bolts - just the new rotors and pads.

Comment: Local dealership can look up the parts and give some specifications, especially fasteners.

Comment: @rj2700, Are you looking to use parts  listed as for, or from, a different vehicle? In most cases if the part is listed as compatible, it will be. Granted there are situations where a part is simply not available... But this is unlikely to occur with Rotors for your Impreza.

Comment: The VIN won't give you enough information to establish the exact parts requirement.  If you want the parts as fitted when the vehicle was new, take the VIN to the Subaru dealership but if they've been changed since manufacture, this won't help you either.  Your best bet is to measure all of the parts currently fitted to your vehicle if you want to be absolutely sure to order the correct parts.

Comment: @NitrusInc Not really, just wanted to make sure if I buy a part, that the OEM specs (since I didn't change anything) fit the new parts.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll give a local dealership a call. This is just one scenario (changing brake systems). In the future, if I need to change some hoses in the engine (coolant, power steering), or I want to replace my seat, etc. I was hoping there would be a centralized way to find information on bolt sizes, materials used, etc. specific to my car (basically, what do I need in order to fix whenever problem).

Comment: @rj2700 As long as it's a reputable aftermarket brand, I am sure it will fit. Akebono, Tokico, StopTech, PowerStop, Bendix, Wearever, Duralast, Wagner etc. If it's a power-brand like "Brembo" and it's cheap, it's a bad idea full-stop. Other than that, if the manufacturer is claiming compatibility it should allow for return without issue if there are any problems with fitment.

Answer (score 1):

A VIN number is a sequence of 17 number and letters that when decoded provide quite a bit of information about a vehicle. When read from left to right.

**WMI( World Manufacturer Identifier) is contained in the first 3 digits.**

**Position 1:** What continent your vehicle was made on.

**Position 2:** What country

**Position 3:** What type of vehicle,

**VDS(Vehicle descriptor Section):**

**Positions 4 through 7:** model info, body type, engine type which is vehicle specific.

**Position 9:** Is a check digit for verication of VIN #- no vehicle info

**VIS(Vehicle identifier section)**

**Position 10:** vehicle year info

**Position 11 through 17:** Plant #, extra options , manufacture sequential number etc which varies from manufacturer to manufacturer.

For vehicle specific information check their websites or talk to the parts department guy at a dealer- the information would probably be on his computer.

https://researchmaniacs.com/VIN/VIN-Decoder.html

Answer (score -1):

Go to opposedforces.com type in what car you have and it will tell a through z bolt nuts spacers washers everything basically a turbo and non turbo model is shown and diagram is pretty easy to understand it helped me hope it helps whoever reads this